# Why is lazy variable initialised multiple times per thread

Tags: kotlin, ktor

I am working on some code where I create a HikariDataSource as a by lazy value. I did apply the mode LazyThreadSafetyMode.SYNCHRONIZED, so I am confused as to why the initialization is done twice when I spin up a new thread that reads that value

```
// in module database
val dataSource: HikariDataSource by lazy(LazyThreadSafetyMode.SYNCHRONIZED) {
    HikariDataSource(dataSourceConfig(databaseConfig))
}

fun initDatabase() {
  dataSource.connect().let { //do stuff}
}

// in main module
fun main() {
  initDatabase()
  thread {
    dataSource.connect().let { // initializes a new data source... }
  }
}
```

I would expect the HikariDataSource to be initialized once, but for some reason its called twice...
I think the fact that I am exposing that variable to another gradle project might affect it, but not sure why..

Answer (score 3):

Well, I think I just answered my own question...

The main module that access the dataSource object is a ktor server that was configured for hot reload..
As soon as I disabled the hotreload and tried again, the variable was not initialized twice.

I guess ktor is doing some stuff with the classloader for hot reload that causes this thing to happen.

Comment: This is a life-saver. Such a nasty issue.